# Solr; What does this mean?

Tags: java, php, full-text-search, apache-tika, solr-cell

At the end of the README.txt file which is located in the example directory under solr, I find this line:

> NOTE: This Solr example server references SolrCell jars outside of the server
>   directory with  statements in the solrconfig.xml.  If you make a copy of
>   this example server and wish to use the ExtractingRequestHandler (SolrCell),
>   you will need to copy the required jars into solr/lib or update the paths to
>   the jars in your solrconfig.xml

What does this mean?

Do I have to make some adjustment before uploading solr to my server?

Also, if you know, what is Solr-nightly:s difference to regular solr?
The tutorial states "solr-nightly.zip" but on their download section I cant find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends whether your are using the ExtractingRequestHandler. Check your config file to see if this is your case (I think you would know it was, because you would have had to specify you want to use it).
See this url : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler